# Adding left and right margin to elements in bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im a little confused why bootstrap wont apply left and right margins to the columns, all i want is a simple row with 3 columns that have like 20px horizontal margin in between each other. If try to do that bootstrap simply clips one of the divs to the next line.

html

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 1</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 1</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 1</p></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.col-md-4 {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 20px 5px;
}
```

Comment: You need to account for the margin. the width is percentage based and doesnt take into account the margin. look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/30tyx5t7/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Left and right margins to the columns would destroy Bootstrap's grid behaviour. Don't modify Bootstrap's classes. **Add** your **own classes** instead.

In your example put an extra `<div>` **in** the column. And give it a margin.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="spacer">
                <p>Box 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="spacer">
                <p>Box 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="spacer">
                <p>Box 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="spacer">
                <p>Box 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="spacer">
                <p>Box 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="spacer">
                <p>Box 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.spacer {
    background-color: tomato;
    margin: 20px 5px;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ndd7u77d/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 7):

for a little more spacing you could do:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap slips one in new row because it column layout is 12 columns max.

When you have *3 divs * (4 col width + margin-right)* you excess the provided 12 columns.

You can set your div a little bit thinner, i.e. 3 medium bootstrap columns, like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 custom-box"><p>Box 1</p></div>
 <div class="col-md-3 custom-box"><p>Box 1</p></div>
 <div class="col-md-3 custom-box"><p>Box 1</p></div>
```

and apply your css rule like this:

```
.custom-box{
    margin-right: 20px 5px!important;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9j628ttz/)